# How to create a utility type to "serialize" an array of objects in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Let's suppose I have the following object type:

```
type Test = {
  date: Date
  num: number
  str: string
}
```

As you can see there is a Date type that I want to convert to a string ("serialize"), so I created the following Generic Type:

```
type Serializer<T extends {[key: string]: unknown}> = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends Date ? string : T[key]
}
```

Which does the job very well, you can check this [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=2&pln=7&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwoF4oG8BQUoBMCGwEAXFACIERZQB2ArgLYl30BGEATlYuydwJbUA5hgC+GDKEhQAyhz54ANnwBeHADwwoEAB6FqOeOgDaAawghewdgMEBdErWonqAewDu1EQD4U6KqfMoASgzEBcAM1h7WACQWy1dCH1DckIoAH4ofiEoEhhY21FxSWgAJQRaBSRUWWtFFXU4RC8MIA).

[image: playground result]

But know, what if I have a `Test[]` type, what generic type could help me "serialize" this data type?

Comment: Wouldn't you just do `type Result = Serializer<Test>[]` to get it as array? Why would you want a serializer generic that takes in an array type?

Comment: Because that's what I have as result of a query, something like the `Test[]` type, but I also have a method that "serialize" that `Test[]` object and transforms the `Date` to a `string`, but unfortunately TS does not infer it, so I have to cast it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve a serializer generic that takes an array as input, you would require a custom `ArrayElement` type that would get the type of an element in your array.

Then your serializer has 2 generic types, the array (`A`) and the array element (`T`) which is equal to `ArrayElement<A>`

Here's an example:

```
type ArrayElement<A> = A extends readonly (infer T)[] ? T : never;

type Serializer<A extends Array<{ [key: string]: unknown }>, T = ArrayElement<A> > = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends Date ? string : T[key];
};

type Result = Serializer<Test>
//  type Result = {
//     date: string;
//     num: number;
//     str: string;
// }
```

Edit: You can one line the `ArrayElement` although I think this gets pretty messy and unreadable.

```
type Serializer<A extends Array<{ [key: string]: unknown }>, T = A extends readonly (infer T)[] ? T : never > = {
  [key in keyof T]: T[key] extends Date ? string : T[key];
};
```

Comment: no need for `infer`, just use `A[number]`

Comment: Btw, at the end of the Serializer type you have to add `[]` to "cast" properly from an array to another array.